# Django Restframework(drf) Bulk Update not working?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, bulkupdate

I am using **djangorestframework-bulk** to perform bulk update have followed documentation [DRF-Bulk](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk) but for me update wasnt working..

it says,

```
File "/webapps/env_apibot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework_bulk/drf3/serializers.py", line 43, in <dictcomp>
    for i in all_validated_data
KeyError: 'my_pk'
```

my configuration was,

**views.py**

```
class MymodelBulkViewSet(BulkModelViewSet):
    model = Mymodel
    queryset = Mymodel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MymodelBulkSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MymodelBulkSerializer(BulkSerializerMixin):
    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
        list_serializer_class = BulkListSerializer
        update_lookup_field = 'my_pk'
```

**models.py**

```
class BillingItem(models.Model):
    my_pk = models.AutoField(max_length=11, primary_key=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
```

but it raise 400 error and it says, key error `my_pk` not found..

**drf version 3.3.2**

**django 1.8.9**

Comment: what is `my_pk` may be you need `pk`?

Comment: its my pk what i am using.. thats table id @BearBrown

Comment: show your model class please

Comment: models.py class added

Answer (score 0):

I have Resolved this with long research finally i found myself..

i tried to override BulkListSerializer now its works fine without i made any changes in it.. i went through finally i found `BulkSerializerMixin`, `BulkListSerializer` getting repeated and it tried to import it from,

```
from rest_framework_bulk import BulkSerializerMixin, BulkListSerializer
```

but actually it should be from,

```
from rest_framework_bulk.drf3.serializers import BulkSerializerMixin, BulkListSerializer
```